# «Не нахожу упоминаний» / «нахожу упоминания» — выбор падежа

Tags: грамматика, падежи, управление

1. *Не нахожу упоминаний* (род. п.) и *нахожу упоминания* (вин. п.): почему частица "не" влияет на падеж?
2. Допустимо ли "не нахожу упоминания" (вин. п.)?

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы изначально запутались с падежами.  [Я] *Не нахожу* (чего?) *упоминания* (Р. п., ед. ч.).  [Я] *Нахожу* (что?) *упоминания* (В. п., мн. ч.).

Comment: Именительного падежа в ваших предложениях быть не может (просто местоимение "я" отсутствует). А склонение существительного «упоминание» можно посмотреть здесь: https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Действ-но, это в. п. Почему частица "не" влияет на падеж (род. п. vs в. п.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формально верным будет "Я не нахожу упоминания (мн. ч. в. п.)".

Запутанность связана с грамматической традицией взаимозаменять формы винительного и родительного падежей в отрицательной форме:

*Я не вижу (кого / что?) руку, маму, совок, цветы, сирень, кровь.

Я не встретил (кого / чего?) руки́, мамы, совка, цветов, сирени, крови.*

Кажется, что предпочтительна форма, которая сохраняет контекст, если учитывать слова, которые дублируются в формах ед/ч р/п и мн/ч в/п *(радости, творения).*

---

- [Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию / Д.Э. Розенталь, Е.В. Джанджакова, Н.П. Кабанова // 45. Управление, §201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091276.html#id-45%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%C2%A7201%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Comment: Т.е. это "5) при выражении дополнения отвлеченными существительными"?